# Detect pressure on screen without finger-like object

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to measure the pressure of something on an android screen, however it can't be detected using an onTouch method because it isn't anything like a finger (something like a bottle, book, etc..).  Is there a way to bypass this, or can the touch screen not read these kinds of objects?

I don't need a specific pressure measurement, just either 0 or 1, but nothing I've found ever addresses this.

Comment: Most Android devices have capacitive touchscreens. They do not work well when touched by non-conductive surfaces, such as a bottle or book.

Comment: i agree with the great android sensei @CommonsWare with this one, most phones are just not able to do that as they are specifically designed to detect specific touch input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a complete answer :

"A capacitive touch screen is a control display that uses the conductive touch of a human finger or a specialized device for input.

Unlike resistive and surface wave panels, which can sense input from either fingers or simple styluses, capacitive touch screen panels must be touched with a finger or a special capacitive pen or glove. The panel is coated with a material that can store electrical charges and the location of touch to the screen is signaled by the change in capacitance in that location."

Most devices these days use capacitive screens and therefore you probably wont be able to achieve what you want to achieve. taken from : https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/capacitive-touch-screen

Comment: Ah. That explains a lot. Thanks